# Pterodactyl Pannel Php Timezone - Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

So i was installing Pterodactyl on Ubuntu and when it was time to enter timezone i went and put one that was invalid (not found) and i cant go any further. i tried editing the file with nano but there is nothing in those. What should i do and here is what the terminal is responding when trying to continue installation procces.

In Creator.php line 87:

Unknown or bad timezone (Canada/Québec)

In CarbonTimeZone.php line 104:

Unknown or bad timezone (Canada/Québec)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

your timezone in your .env is invalid

`nano /var/www/pathtopanel/.env`

And edit your timezone to `America/Toronto`